# How do I search a pandas dataframe to get the row with a cell matching a specified value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that might look like this:

```
print(df_selection_names)

                             name
0  fatty red meat, like prime rib
0                         grilled
```

I have another dataframe, `df_everything`, with columns called `name`, `suggestion` and a lot of other columns. I want to find all the rows in `df_everything` with a `name` value matching the `name` values from `df_selection_names` so that I can print the values for each `name` and `suggestion` pair, e.g., "suggestion1 is suggested for name1", "suggestion2 is suggested for name2", etc.

I've tried several [ways to get cell values from a dataframe](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-cell-value-from-pandas-dataframe/)  and [searching for values within a row](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-search-a-value-within-a-pandas-dataframe-row/) including

```
# number of items in df_selection_names = df_selection_names.shape[0]
# so, in other words, we are looping through all the items the user selected
for i in range(df_selection_names.shape[0]):
    # get the cell value using at() function
    # in 'name' column and i-1 row
    sel = df_selection_names.at[i, 'name']
    # this line finds the row 'sel' in df_everything
    row = df_everything[df_everything['name'] == sel]
```

but everything I tried gives me `ValueErrors`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) leads me to think I may be
*way* off, but I'm feeling pretty confused about everything at this point!

Comment: So, what's in `df_everything`?  Remember that you must have an exact match for "fatty read meat, like prime rib".  It won't match "prime rib".]

Comment: `df_selection_names` is a subset of `df_everything`, so it _should_ be an exact match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html?highlight=isin#pandas.Series.isin

```
df_everything[df_everything['name'].isin(df_selection_names["name"])]
```